# Delphi TAdsQuery is NOT static. How to make it static

Tags: delphi, static, infinite-loop, advantage-database-server

I've ran into this issue before, and know how to get around it, but I'd like to know if there is a property I'm missing, or better way.
My solution is to get a record count, then iterate by the count, vs looking for EOF.

Is there a better way?

What happens is the query result re-reads the Source.dbf AFTER the post. You never reach EOF, and the loop is infinite.

Consider the following code. For Simplicity, Source.dbf is a single record table, with a single field (named Field1). Field1 in Record 1 has the value of '123'.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateSourceTable;
  CreateQuery;

  while not Qry.EOF do
  begin
    tblSource.Append;
    tblSource.FieldByName('Field1').AsString := '123';
    tblSource.Post;
    Qry.Next;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateQuery;
begin
  Qry := TAdsQuery.Create(self);
  Qry.TableType := ttADSCdx;
  Qry.DatabaseName := 'c:\project\windows\tools\StaticQuery';
  Qry.SQL.Add('Select * from Source');
  Qry.SQL.Add('where Field1 = ''123''');
  Qry.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateSourceTable;
begin
  tblSource := TAdsTable.Create(self);
  tblSource.DatabaseName := 'c:\project\windows\tools\StaticQuery';
  tblSource.TableName := 'Source.dbf';
  tblSource.TableType := ttADSCdx;
  tblSource.Open;
end;
```

Comment: The point of EOF iteration is that many client libraries are fetching tuples whilst doing that. If you were having all the tuples fetched on the client side, you could have read data from the client buffer. But what you're afraid of is impossible because you're working in a single thread, so there's no way to execute any other method (like e.g. `CreateSourceTable`) whilst the iteration is running inside the `Button1Click` event handler.

Comment: What @Victoria says is correct. The behaviour you are trying to avoid is what you should expect, with a file-system type database at any rate, if you take no steps to avoid it.  But relying on `RecordCount` to do anything is rarely a good idea.  This smells like an XY problem.  What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve with your `while` loop?

Comment: Btw, the premise of your q is incorrect.  `TQuery` is a `TDataSet` descendant with its own implementation, designed to handle operations with the obsolete BDE.  `TAdsQuery` and `TAdsTable` are **not** descendants of it.

Comment: @MartynA That's not what their website says: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.1/mergedprojects/ade/sec7/tadsquery.htm

Comment: Sorry, @JerryDodge, what is not what that article says?

Comment: @MartynA I guess it is a bit misleading what they say... `"TAdsQuery is a TDataSet descendant component that provides an encapsulation of TQuery functionality and Advantage extended methods using the Advantage Database Server through the Advantage Client Engine."`

Comment: @JerryDodge:  I would take that to mean that it is a TQuery work-alike (which was all the rage once upon a time), not a Delphi descendant of the TQuery class.  I'd find it difficult to believe that it would require the BDE DLLs, though truth is sometimes stranger than fiction, of course.

Comment: >> What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve with your while loop? – MartynA.                                                                                      
                                                                                                        
Working through a 'tickler' system that adds new items and can complete and new items. The example was made as simple as possible to show the non-static nature.

Comment: "The example was made as simple as possible" Ok, well done.  I think my answer explains why this happens and a way to avoid it.

Comment: @JerryDodge: You've deleted the comment I objected to, so mine is no longer relevant; I've deleted it as well.

Comment: @JerryDodge: As I said, the comment to which I responded has since been deleted, and I've deleted my response to it as well, so the discussion is moot in any case.

Comment: @KenWhite, Jerrry:  I'll take the wrap for this, for mentioning the BDE in the first place.  The "premise" I was challenging was the one underlying the original title of the q, that TQuery has anything to do with TAdQuery's behaviour.

Comment: @MartynA: Thanks. I don't know what the issue is at this point anyway, or why it's still being discussed. The comments in question were deleted by both of us, so any continuation is unnecessary. (Nice answer too, BTW.)

Comment: @MartynA If Ken really did see a comment from me, it wasn't really me. Not only was I not on this post until after your comment, but I don't know enough about the subject to have even said such a thing. I was merely quoting what the vendor's website said, and followed up by also saying it's misleading.

Answer (score 3):

The (D7) documentation for `TDataSet.Append` stated

> A newly appended record is posted to the database in one of three ways:
>   For indexed Paradox and dBASE tables, the record is inserted into the dataset in a position based on its index.
>       For unindexed Paradox and dBASE tables, the record is added to the end of the dataset.
>       For SQL databases, the physical location of the appended record is implementation-specific. For indexed tables, the index is updated with the new record information.

I mention D7 because TAdsTable and TAdsQuery date from around that era, or a bit before, and were
intended to be similar to TTable and TQuery, which were for working with datasets implemented using
te obsolete BDE (Borland Database Engine).

In the example you quote, you have a dataset with a single field and you are repeatedly appending
records with indistinguishable values ('123') into it, and the behaviour you see is similar
to what you would get if you repeatedly added identical records to a `file of record` while
traversing it in physical order.

I don't have the Advantage components myself, but can confirm that the same endless loop
occurs with a BDE TQuery and TTable.  The reason is obvious (and I would expect the same
explanation would be true of Advatage):

- Operations on the Table cannot affect the current cursor state of the Query, BUT
- the Query re-evaluates its EOF condition after each call to `Next` and `Next` always
  succeeds because the records added by the Table are indistinguishable from the others
  found by the `Query`'s WHERE condition.  There is no way of avoiding that while
  the `Query` and the `Table` are both accessing the same underlying dataset and
  the rows added by the `Table` satisfy the `Query`'s WHERE clause.  A bit to my surprise, this endless loop behaviour occurs even when the `TQuery`'s `RequestLive` property is false.

So, if you cannot avoid the WHERE clause point, the simplest way to avoid the problem
would be to iterate a temporary copy of the dataset, rather than the dataset itself, e.g. by using Advantage's equivalent
of the BDE's `TBatchMove` component to create the copy table and then iterare that instead of thQuery`'s result set.  I hope the code necessary to do this is self-evident, but if not I could add a BDE example.

Btw, if the TAdsQuery supports `Append` or `Insert`, you realise that youu could dispense with the `TAdsTable` and add the extra rows using the `TAdsQuery`